# Group by Day or Most Recent Value Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table using postgresql:

```
Date        Group   Count   Days
31/01/2021  Gr1     50      5
30/01/2021  Gr2     40      10
29/01/2021  Gr1     30      6
28/01/2021  Gr2     20      4
27/01/2021  Gr1     10      5
26/01/2021  Gr2     40      8
25/01/2021  Gr1     30      6
24/01/2021  Gr2     10      5
23/01/2021  Gr1     5       1
```

What I want to is produce a table for group 1 (GR1) by day, produce the count and calculate 'Average Count Per Day' as Count/Days. Where GR1 is not produced for a day then use the previous days which was a GR1 day. For example where GR1 does not have a value for 30-01-2021 then use the values from the most recent earlier day which it was GR (i.e. 29-01-2021).

The result should look like this:

```
Date            Group   Count   Days    Avg Count Per Days
31/01/2021      Gr1     50      5       10
30/01/2021      Gr1     30      6       5
29/01/2021      Gr1     30      6       5
28/01/2021      Gr1     10      5       2
27/01/2021      Gr1     10      5       2
26/01/2021      Gr1     30      6       5
25/01/2021      Gr1     30      6       5
24/01/2021      Gr1     5       1       5
23/01/2021      Gr1     5       1       5
```

Comment: Can there be more than one Gr1 entry in your table for a single date?

Answer (score 0):

First I get all rows where `"Group" = 'Gr1'` and calculate "Avg Count Per Days" (`subquery grp1`). Then I generate all days between `MIN("Date")` and `MAX("Date")` (`subquery days`). Finally I `JOIN` boths subqueries and for each day I get most recent value not null (actual value or previous most recent value), using `window function FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
WITH  grp1 AS (SELECT *, "Count" / "Days" AS "Avg Count Per Days" 
               FROM t 
               WHERE "Group" = 'Gr1'),

      days AS (SELECT generate_series(MIN("Date"), MAX("Date"), INTERVAL '1 day')::date AS day
              FROM grp1)
              
SELECT DISTINCT 
       days.day AS "Date",
       FIRST_VALUE("Group") OVER (PARTITION BY days.day ORDER BY "Date" DESC) AS "Group",
       FIRST_VALUE("Count") OVER (PARTITION BY days.day ORDER BY "Date" DESC) AS "Count",
       FIRST_VALUE("Days") OVER (PARTITION BY days.day ORDER BY "Date" DESC) AS "Days",
       FIRST_VALUE("Avg Count Per Days") OVER (PARTITION BY days.day ORDER BY "Date" DESC) AS "Avg Count Per Days"
FROM days
LEFT JOIN grp1 ON grp1."Date" <= days.day
ORDER BY days.day DESC;
```

I assuming you have not more than 1 row `"Group" = 'Gr1'` by day.